# how do I implement the "remind me later" button using async storage?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, asyncstorage

there are modulke in my project that is called after a successful operation of money transfer. After a successful operation, I suggest that the user evaluate the app. And the app evaluation is called after each successful operation, which is a bit annoying. How do I add a "remind me later" button and implement it using async storage?  thank you in advance!

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import RateModal from 'react-native-store-rating';

export default class RateAppModal extends Component {
  state = {
    isModalOpen: true,
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <RateModal
          modalTitle="Оцените наше приложение"
          rateBtnText="Оценить"
          cancelBtnText="Отмена"
          totalStarCount={5}
          defaultStars={0}
          isVisible
          sendBtnText="Отправить"
          commentPlaceholderText="Оставьте комментарий..."
          emptyCommentErrorMessage="Empty comment error message"
          playStoreUrl="market://details?id=com.smb.client.mobile"
          iTunesStoreUrl="itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/app/id1497101549"
          isModalOpen={this.state.isModalOpen}
          storeRedirectThreshold={0}
          style={{
            paddingHorizontal: 30,
          }}
          onStarSelected={(e) => {
            console.log('change rating', e);
          }}
          onClosed={() => {
            console.log('pressed cancel button...');
            this.setState({
              isModalOpen: false,
            });
          }}
          sendContactUsForm={(state) => {
            alert(JSON.stringify(state));
          }}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First initialized the storage key you would use and set it to false
`AsyncStorage.getItem('RemindMeLater', (err, result) => !result && AsyncStorage.setItem('RemindMeLater', false))`

When the remind me later button is pressed, you can set the storage to true by
`AsyncStorage.setItem('RemindMeLater', true)`

Then check for the storage when u needed to display the modal again by `AsyncStorage.getItem('RemindMeLater', (err, result) => result ? this.setState({isModalOpen:true}) : null)`

Comment: I need that when the cancel button is clicked, the current date is saved in AsyncStorage and the next successful operation checks the date, and if a week has passed since the "first cancellation", the RateApp modal window is displayed. Can you help?

Comment: You can just change the value of the storage from boolean to date time string and compare. @Madiever

Comment: thank you, it turns out that the project has a ready-made utility for this. but your advice still helped me to understand the point.

Answer (score 0):

yes, async storge is the answer you can place a flag in storge and remember about the user selection or another way is to store it on the back end but not recommended